# I want to do look up on excel file to add new row in excel file in all sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I have one excel file with `100 sheets`

My problem is I want to do [image]

> I want to check if I found "Name" In any "Attribute" column.

Then Add new row of record `"DisplayName"`  with same values what `"Name"` having but `"IsMandatory"` is `"N"`

There are 400 sheets where I need to check and insert new row if I found "Name" in "Attribute" column

Please give me idea . How can I do it using excel lookup or pivot technique. ?

Comment: you could do it quite easily with `Range.Find` method (strongly supported by Macro Recorder). `.Find` method return Range Object which allows you to manipulate with rows insertion (`.Insert`) and other cells references like `.Offset`, etc. This is all you need, I think.

Comment: @KazJaw Can you pleaes share any example link so that I can do it.Sorry I'm new to this. Thanks a lot

Comment: run Excel Macro Recorder first and analyse the code. second- search for `[excel-vba] .find` here in SO to get plenty of samples and explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Test()
Dim curWorkbook As Workbook
Dim rnge As Range
Dim pasteCell As Integer

Set curWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

For Each wrkSheet In curWorkbook.Worksheets
    wrkSheet.Activate
    pasteCell = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    wrkSheet.Range("A:A").Select

    Set rnge = Selection.Find(What:="Name", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If rnge Is Nothing Then
        '//Do Nothing
    Else
        wrkSheet.Range("A" & rnge.Row & ":D" & rnge.Row).Copy _
                    Destination:=wrkSheet.Range("A" & pasteCell & ":D" & pasteCell)
        wrkSheet.Range("A" & pasteCell).Value = "Display Name"
        wrkSheet.Range("C" & pasteCell).Value = "N"
        Set rnge = Nothing
    End If
    wrkSheet.Range("A1").Select
Next
End Sub
```

I am assuming the column references will remain same (A:D). If the columns will change in each individual sheet, you will have first find the correct column in the worksheet and then search for "Name" attribute in that column.

Comment: How many rows with values in Column A are there in each sheet?